# Is there any way to make certain snippets automatically expand without confirmation?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I have certain snippets for which I want to write the prefix, and for the snippet to expand automatically, without me having to press "TAB" or any confirmation key.

An example snippet for which I want to do that for is

```
"to the power of": {
  "prefix": "tothe",
  "body": [
    "^{$1}$2 $0"
  ],
  "description": "to the power of"
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: The extension HyperSnips can do that, the built-in snippets can not.

Comment: make a keybinding that inserts a snippet

Comment: Hi @Mark, thank you for the comment. Your suggestion does almost exactly what I wanted. The only thing that seems to be off is that I can't execute manual snippets within snippets. More precisely, I still have some snippets that I want to keep non-automated, and when I try to execute them in the snippet environment I just go to the next placeholder instead of executing the snippet. I tried disabling 'Editor > Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions' but it still doesn't work. Any thoughts on how to fix that?